# Question about the next() function in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the concept of the next() function in express.js. I guess my first question would be is next() an express.js only function? My second question would be, in the example below what does next do? After the console function, it goes to the next function that is called after? I'm so confused.

```
var cb0 = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('CB0');
  next();
}
```

Comment: `is next() an expressjs only function` - no, any javascript code can have a function called `next` ... but `next` is just "conventional" name for that third argument in express - your code above would be equally valid if written `var cb0 = function (req, res, frank) {
  console.log('CB0')
  frank()` - read this [middleware documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) for the uses of this callback

Answer (score 5):

With Express (and other similar systems), each request passes through a series of *middleware* functions (like your `cb0`). Each of those has a chance to do something with the request.

Since the thing a middleware function does may be asynchronous (for instance, reading a file, querying a database, etc.), Express can't just directly call the next bit of middleware after calling the previous one. So instead, it passes the middleware function a function, `next`, which that middleware uses to say "I'm done, run the next step." (In the Express version, you can also pass an argument to `next`, as [Aikon Mogwai points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794780/question-about-the-next-function-in-expressjs/55794858?noredirect=1#comment98258665_55794858): If you pass it an `Error`, it triggers error handling for the route. If you pass it `"route"`, it jumps to the next router, etc.).

So the concept of a `next` function isn't specific to Express, but the specific use in that example is.

Here's a much simplified example not using Express, but demonstrating the sort of thing it does with middleware functions when handling a request:

```js
const app = {
  middleware: [],
  use(callback) {
    this.middleware.push(callback);
  }
};

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("First handler synchronous part");
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("First handler async part finished");
    next();
  }, 800);
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Second handler is entirely synchronous");
  next();
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Third handler synchronous part");
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("Third handler async part finished");
    next();
  }, 800);
});

// Code handling an incoming request
function handleRequest(req, app) {
  // Copy the handlers
  const middleware = app.middleware.slice();
  // Create a "response"
  const res = {};
  // Call the handlers
  let index = 0;
  next();
  function next() {
    if (index < middleware.length) {
      // Call the handler, have it call `next` when it's done
      middleware[index++](req, res, next);
    } else {
      console.log("Request completed");
    }
  }
}

handleRequest({}, app);
```

---

It's probably worth mentioning that this manual-style of asynchronous middleware handling has been replaced with promises in [Koa.js](https://koajs.com/), which is a new(er) framework from the same people who did Express.js. With Koa, you make your callbacks `async` functions, and Koa's internals wait for the promise the `async` function returns to settle and then acts on the result of it setting (e.g., rejection or fulfillment, the value it fulfills with, etc.).

Comment: Also: `next(err)` is equals to `throw err;` in the middleware and `next('route')` can be use to jump to next router.

Answer (score 3):

Next is used to pass control to the next middleware function. If not the request will be left hanging or open. Calling this function invokes the next middleware function in the app. The next() function is not a part of the Node.js or Express API but is the third argument that is passed to the middleware function.

Comment: *If not the request will be left hanging or open* - only of there was no response. *The next() function is not a part of the Node.js or Express API* - it's a part of Express API because Express calls middleware function and provides it with `next` argument.

Answer (score 2):

The `next()` function requests the next middleware function in the application. The `next()` function is not a part of the Node.js or Express API, but it is the third case/argument which is passing to the middleware function. The `next()` function could be named anything, but by convention, it is always named "next". **To avoid confusion, always use this convention.**

For more info, you can visit the official tutorial of [express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

var CB0 = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('CB0')
  next()
}

app.use(CB0)

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Each and Every time app receives a request and prints the message "CB0" console in terminal window.

The middleware functions that are loaded first are also executed first.

The middleware function CB0 simply prints a message, then passes on the request to the next middleware function in the stack by calling the next() function.